# How to pass a text file or it's path as parameter and read the file into an oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, file, stored-procedures, oracle12c

I want to pass a file path (which might be in C or D drive or anywhere on a server) as a parameter to an oracle stored procedure and read the file inside of it. Is it possible to do? How can I do that? What kind of variables are used to do so? I am using oracle12C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Reading a file" - as far as I understood the question - means "using `UTL_FILE` package".

As `UTL_FILE` reads data from a **directory** (an Oracle object which points to a filesystem directory, the one you see on the hard disk), your DBA has to

- create directory
- grant you (i.e. user which will use that procedure) `read` an/or `write` privileges on that directory

Directory is usually located on the database server; it can be its `C` or `D` drive, but not exactly as you put it "*anywhere*" - unless DBA is willing to create that many directories (I doubt it).

Then you'll be able to access that file and work on it.

---

Alternatively, you might even use an **external table** - it works as an "ordinary" table so you can write `SELECT` statement directly against it. In the background, it uses SQL*Loader. Still, file must be located in previously mentioned directory.

---

Finally, **SQL*Loader** itself: its benefit is that file you'd like to load resides on your PC, it doesn't have to be on the server. You'd create a control file (which says how to read the file), load data into a table and do whatever you want.